# MapReduce For Clustering Red and Blue Balls in Two Bags

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

suppose There Are Two Bags(Set with repeated items in Math - Not Real Physical Bags) R and S with large number blue and red balls inside.
how can use MapReduce Algorithm to cluster(Separation) red balls in "R bag" and Blue balls in "S bags"

```
 examle :    R={redBall,blueBall,redBall,redBall ...}
             S={blueBall,redBall,blueball,,redBall....}
```

What is Map and Reduce Functions Input output + simple code body?

Mapper:input()?
Maper :Body?
Mapper(output)?

Reduce:input()?
Reduce:Body code?

Reduce:Result(R={All Red balls}, S={All Blue Balls})

i think map function input must be

```
key=name of Bags Value-list = Balls inside Bag
output (R,<RedBall,BlueBall ,...> )(S,<BlueBall,BlueBall,RedBall,...> )
```

then group (Shuffled) and 
**FINAL Reduce Result**

```
<R,RedBall  RedBall,...> :it is R Bag

<S,BlueBall BlueBall,...> it is S Bag
```

**Note**:Bags here is not Real Bags bag is same with set={} .with repeated items (in Massive Dateset book called Bag)

Can We Break into Multi Bags Same name?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect as inputs and outputs? Balls and bags don't sound like things that computer programs act upon.

Comment: i add some information to Questions ..Bags Are as Set with repeated Items.S={RedBall,BlueBall,RedBall}..since in set only one time apear RedBall we Called Bag to repeat items